# Thymeleaf th:inline="javascript" issue

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I don't know how to solve the following: I'd like to let my Model generate real javascript dynamically based on some model logic.

This final piece of javascript code then should be added inside the *$(document).ready { }* part of my html page.

The thing is: If I use inline="javascript", the code gets quoted as my getter is a String (that is how it is mentioned in the Thymeleaf doc but it's not what I need ;-)

If I use inline="text" in is not quoted but all quotes are escaped instead ;-) - also nice but unusable 8)

If I try inline="none" nothing happens.

Here are the examples

My model getter created the following Javascript code.

**PageHelper class**

```
public String documentReady() {

// do some database operations to get the numbers 8,5,3,2
return "PhotoGallery.load(8,5,3,2).loadTheme(name='basic')";

}
```

So if I now try **inline="javascript"**

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        /*[[${pageHelper.documentReady}]]*/
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

it will be rendered to

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        'PhotoGallery.load(8,5,3,2).loadTheme(name=\'basic\')'
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Which doesn't help as it is a String literal, nothing more (this is how Thymeleaf deals with it).

So if I try **inline="text"** instead

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        PhotoGallery.load(8,5,3,2).loadTheme(name=&#39;basic&#39;)
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Which escapes the quotes.

**inline="none"** I do not really understand, as it does nothing

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        [[${pageHelper.documentReady}]]
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

To be honest I have no idea how to solve this issue and hopefully anybody out there knows how to deal with this.

Many thanks in advance
Cheers
John

Comment: Well you can always use `eval()`, although it is definitely not the prettiest solution.

Comment: Hi Kejml. Thanks for that quick help. And indeed eval() works ;-) What a dirty hack. Had to google eval() as I definitly could not really remember but at the end, my `inline="javascript"` in conjunction with `eval([[${pageHelper.documentReady}]])` really worked out well. Although I would like to keep that question unansered for a moment to see, if there is an "official" Thymeleaf way of doing this. Anyhow. Many thanks again. Cheers. John.

Comment: Sure, I don't think this is right way of doing it, that's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer, but it least it can get you going. Hopefully someone will come with correct answer. Cheers :)

Comment: I think the problem is the way you are defining your script. It would be much better if you put the actual method call in the script and generate the inputs in the server sid. something like this : PhotoGallery.load(8,5,3,2).loadTheme(/*[[${pageHelper.inputs}]]*/)

Comment: That's because Thymeleaf generates values for the javascript in  the way you are using it. so either use the eval function, or change your approche to something like what I've said

Comment: Hi Hossein. I am with you. The idea behind that is a bit different. Based on information in my database I know, what JavaScripts are required in the actual Thymeleaf template. And based on that I only want to create the required JS code, to keep really only the needed one for runtime. Therefore the whole `PhotoGallery.load(8,5,3,2).loadTheme(name=\'basic\')` part is the dynamic one. If it is not needed, it's simply empty. And there are more portions like this. But I left them out to not over complicated my posting. It's some kind of dynamic include.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would change the approach.

Thymeleaf easily allows you to add model variables in your templates to be used in Javascript. In my implementations, I usually put those variables somewhere before the closing header tag; to ensure they're on the page once the JS loads.

I let the template decide what exactly to load, of course. If you're displaying a gallery, then render it as you would and use data attributes to define the gallery that relates to some JS code. Then write yourself a nice [jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) to handle your gallery.

A relatively basic example:

Default Layout Decorator: layout/default.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>My Example App</title>
  <object th:remove="tag" th:include="fragments/scripts :: header" />
</head>
<body>
  <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
  <div th:remove="tag" th:replace="fragments/scripts :: footer"></div>
  <div th:remove="tag" layout:fragment="footer-scripts"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing to notice here is the inclusion of the generic footer scripts and then a `layout:fragment` div defined. This layout div is what we're going to use to include our jQuery plugin needed for the gallery.

File with general scripts: fragments/scripts.html

```
<div th:fragment="header" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var MY_APP = {
      contextPath: /*[[@{/}]]*/,
      defaultTheme: /*[[${theme == null} ? null : ${theme}]]*/,
      gallery: {
        theme: /*[[${gallery == null} ? null : ${gallery.theme}]]*/,
        images: /*[[${gallery == null} ? null : ${gallery.images}]]*/,
        names: /*[[${gallery == null} ? null : ${gallery.names}]]*/
      }
    };
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
</div>
<div th:fragment="footer" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_app.js"></script>
</div>
```

In the scripts file, there are 2 fragments, which are included from the decorator. In the header fragment, a helpful context path is included for the JS layer, as well as a `defaultTheme` just for the hell of it. A gallery object is then defined and assigned from our model. The footer fragment loads the jQuery library and a main site JS file, again for purposes of this example.

A page with a lazy-loaded gallery: products.html

```
<html layout:decorator="layout/default" xmlns:layout="http://www.thymeleaf.org/" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Products Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div data-gallery="lazyload"></div>
  </div>
  <div th:remove="tag" layout:fragment="footer-scripts">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_gallery.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Our products page doesn't have much on it. Using the default decorator, this page overrides the page title in the head. Our content fragment includes a title in an h1 tag and an empty div with a data-gallery attribute. This attribute is what we'll use in our jQuery plugin to initialize the gallery.

The value is set to lazyload, so our plugin knows that we need to find the image IDs in some variable set somewhere. This could have easily been empty if the only thing our plugin supports is a lazyloaded gallery.

So the layout loads some default scripts and with cleverly placed `layout:fragments`, you allow certain sections of the site to load libraries independent of the rest.

Here's a basic Spring controller example, to work with our app: MyController.java

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping("/products")
  public String products(Model model) {        
    class Gallery {
      public String theme;
      public int[] images;
      public String[] names;
      public Gallery() {
        this.theme = "basic";
        this.images = new int[] {8,5,3,2};
        this.names = new String[] {"Hey", "\"there's\"", "foo", "bar"};
      }
    }
    model.addAttribute("gallery", new Gallery());
    return "products";
  }
}
```

The Gallery class was tossed inline in the products method, to simplify our example here. This could easily be a service or repository of some type that returns an array of identifiers, or whatever you need.

The jQuery plugin that we created, could look something like so: my_gallery.js

```
(function($) {
  var MyGallery = function(element) {
    this.$el = $(element);
    this.type = this.$el.data('gallery');
    if (this.type == 'lazyload') {
      this.initLazyLoadedGallery();
    }
  };

  MyGallery.prototype.initLazyLoadedGallery = function() {
    // do some gallery loading magic here
    // check the variables we loaded in our header
    if (MY_APP.gallery.images.length) {
      // we have images... sweet! let's fetch them and then do something cool.
      PhotoGallery.load(MY_APP.gallery.images).loadTheme({
        name: MY_APP.gallery.theme
      });
      // or if load() requires separate params
      var imgs = MY_APP.gallery.images;
      PhotoGallery.load(imgs[0],imgs[1],imgs[2],imgs[3]).loadTheme({
        name: MY_APP.gallery.theme
      });
    }
  };

  // the plugin definition
  $.fn.myGallery = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, 'myGallery')) {
        $.data(this, 'myGallery', new MyGallery(this));
      }
    });
  };

  // initialize our gallery on all elements that have that data-gallery attribute
  $('[data-gallery]').myGallery();
}(jQuery));
```

The final rendering of the products page would look like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Products Landing Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var MY_APP = {
      contextPath: '/',
      defaultTheme: null,
      gallery: {
        theme: 'basic',
        images: [8,5,3,2],
        names: ['Hey','\"there\'s\"','foo','bar']
      }
    };
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div data-gallery="lazyload"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_gallery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, Thymeleaf does a pretty good job of translating your model to valid JS and actually adds the quotes where needed and escapes them as well. Once the page finishes rendering, with the jQuery plugin at the end of the file, everything needed to initialize the gallery should be loaded and ready to go.

This is *not* a perfect example, but I think it's a pretty straight-forward design pattern for a web app.

Comment: Hi Yorgo, thanks for that great explanation. It seems that I really have to refactor my approach as you proposed. I already suspected it after Kejml and Hossein have  indicated that too. So thanks to everybody. Cheers John

Comment: I would have expected that there is no backslash before the double quote in html. Why would Thymeleaf escape the double quote when it is not really needed.

Comment: Good question T3rm1. I don't recall how I got the final output there... most likely did a view source, copy/paste. I did have them escaped in the sample controller I included, so I assume it was just Thymeleaf retaining it from the original string.

Answer (score -4):

instead of `${pageHelper.documentReady}` use `${pageHelper.documentReady}`