# Thymeleaf for a URL in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, thymeleaf

my question is as following:

1. The project base url is : **http://servername/sampelProjectName**
2. The test page url is :**http://servername/sampelProjectName/user/home**
   ,in this page I had include a javascript file - datatable.packer.js ,which   i had included it using below code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/datatable.packer.js}"></script>
```

In the above **datatable.packer.js** file ,there's a ajax call ,the ajax call url is: "/api/test",like below definition:

```
var url="/api/test";
```

3. then when i access the   **http://servername/sampelProjectName/user/home** page ,the ajax call url parsed to : "http://servername/user/home/api/test " ,not the expected url "http://servername/sampelProjectName/api/test", and also if changed the url definition to **"api/test"** ,then it will parse to url : "http://servername/api/test" ...

any suggestion for this problem ? how to use the url in javascript code ?  thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a JS block where you define the URL. 
not sure how elegant it is but definitely works

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    apiUrl = "http://servername/sampelProjectName/api/test";
   /*]]>*/
</script>
```

and I think this way your js code will be able to see that variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,it can work anyway, also refer this page for the th:inline usage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596600/thymeleaf-thinline-javascript-issue