# Thymleaf to avoid masking JS code

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to replace within my Spring MVC Controller a closing script-tag to a stripped one:

```
String cleaned = previewCode.getPreview_code().replace("/script", "/scr\"+\"ipt");
model.addAttribute("prev_code", cleaned);
```

And put those "cleaned" JS code into my Thymeleaf Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    document.write([[${prev_code}]]);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

But the result will be that Thymeleaf obviously masked the result:

```
document.write("<script src='http:\/\/blaw.net\/some.js'><\/scr\"+\"ipt>
```

with the additional slashes in the stripped tag. Which won't work.

So, how to tell Thymeleaf to take the JS as it is and don't do anything with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf th:inline="javascript" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596600/thymeleaf-thinline-javascript-issue)

Comment: You could try `th:inline="text"`, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to replace `</script>`with `</scr"+"pt>` which is useful within `document.write(...)` but thymelaf wont use as it replaced in java instead it masked to `<\/scr\"+\"ipt>`.