# Update a table in thymeleaf without page refresh

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    var senderLogin = [[${senderLogin}]]
    var recipientLogin = [[${recipientLogin}]]
    function CheckAndGetMessage() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url: '/get_updated_dialog',
            data: {'senderLogin':senderLogin, 'recipientLogin':recipientLogin },
            success: function (messageList) {
                document.getElementById("messageList_local").value = messageList;
                $('#message_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                return;
            }

        });
    };

    setInterval(CheckAndGetMessage,1000);
```

Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get_updated_dialog",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Message>  getUpdatedDialog(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam("senderLogin") String  senderLogin, @RequestParam("recipientLogin") String  recipientLogin, Model model){
    List<Message> messageList = messageService.UpdatedDialogBetweenUsers( recipientLogin, senderLogin,authentication, model);
    return messageList; }
```

Another Java code:

```
model.addAttribute("messageList", messageList);
```

(Attribute is adding in function which returns a view with table page)

My table:

```
<div id="messageList_local" th:with="messageList_local=${messageList}">
    <table id="message_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <span th:each="message : ${messageList}"> <!-- close tags and etc -->
```

I tried to call this in JS:

```
                document.getElementById("messageList_local").value = messageList;
            $('#message_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

But my table did not refresh. P.S. I checked with debugger that getUpdatedDialog returns a list with updated messages.

Comment: Your javascript sees problematic to me (but i am not sure). Please use Thymeleaf inline JS functionality properly as stated in the answer of this SO question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596600/thymeleaf-thinline-javascript-issue You should be using proper CDATA syntax. Maybe without the use of CDATA syntax your senderLogin and recipientLogin values are not set properly.

Comment: By the way you should be using fragments to do AJAX stuff but it is impossible to see if you already did that since you didnt include the complete code of the view. In addition to the fragment use you should return a fragmen view.