# Ampersand parsed as &amp; in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, parsing, thymeleaf

Here's my thymeleaf template:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
       function postForm() {
          window.location.href = '[[${azSsoUrl}]]';
       }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="postForm()">
</body>
</html>
```

actual value of `azSsoUrl`:

```
http://localhost:8080/gc-restful/sso-login?spEntityID=someId&metaAlias=%2FEmployee;
```

but after parsing, this is what I get in the response. Note that `&` becomes
`&amp;`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
       function postForm() {
          window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/gc-restful/sso-login?spEntityID=someId&amp;metaAlias=%2FEmployee;';
       }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="postForm()">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not really sure, using `[[${azSsoUrl}]]` is the right way to do this. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

I tried various things mentioned in the answer of possible duplicate question. But nothing seems to fix my problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Please ask a question.

Comment: Since that seems like a String to me, have you tried using \\& for encoding the ampersand? Or alternatively, calling encodeURIComponent(yourURL)? As a last resort, the URL-escape sign for the & is %26.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf th:inline="javascript" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596600/thymeleaf-thinline-javascript-issue)

Comment: @naXa I saw that question. But can't find anything that'll solve my problem. Do tell if I'm wrong

Comment: Why do you think it's not working (what is the actual error)? I tested it, and even though the `&`s were encoded, everything worked for me.   I don't think there is any way you will be able to output an `&` using thymeleaf.  You can specify `<script th:inline="javascript">` for a different style of encoding, I guess.

Comment: Did you try unescaped inlining `[(${azSsoUrl})]`? I know zip about thymeleaf but I saw some examples :-(

Comment: Sorry, now I see your question is different. I just found a question I thought was similar so I posted a link under your question in the hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving my problem. It seems `th:inline="javascript"` is required with the script tag.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
       function postForm() {

          /*<![CDATA[*/

          window.location.href = /*[[${azSsoUrl}]]*/ 'redirect url';

          /*]]>*/
       }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="postForm()">
</body>
</html>
```